# How to save selected radiobutton to a text file using html codes

Tags: javascript, html

I used a code from another thread on this website to save form data to text file on local hard disk.  For text field it worked fine but when i tried to save the data of a radiobutton it didn't happen i tried several combinations but still it didn't worked.
The Code Used by me is as below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      form * {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script language="Javascript" >
      function download(filename, text) {
        var pom = document.createElement('a');
        pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 
                         encodeURIComponent(text));
        
        pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

        pom.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(pom);

        pom.click();

        document.body.removeChild(pom);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
      <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
      <textarea rows=3 cols=50 name="text">PLEASE WRITE ANSWER HERE. </textarea>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Option 1" onclick="getElementById('problem').value=this.value;"> Option 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Option 2" onclick="getElementById('problem').value=this.value;"> Option 2<br>
      <input type="text" name="problem" id="problem">
      <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My email id is 
saurabhsrivastava37@gmail.com

Comment: I'm still surprised at the number of people that invite spam by posting their email address in a public forum. Especially one where all replies are sent to email anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to pass this parameter to the function `download` too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      form * {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script language="Javascript" >
      function download(filename, text, text1) {
        var pom = document.createElement('a');
        pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 
                         encodeURIComponent(text + '\r\n' + text1));
        
        pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

        pom.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(pom);

        pom.click();

        document.body.removeChild(pom);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value, this['problem'].value)">
      <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
      <textarea rows=3 cols=50 name="text">PLEASE WRITE ANSWER HERE. </textarea>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Option 1" onclick="getElementById('problem').value=this.value;"> Option 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Option 2" onclick="getElementById('problem').value=this.value;"> Option 2<br>
      <input type="text" name="problem" id="problem">
      <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply is working but the text file which i am getting is having all data in a single line. is there a way so that i could code a format the text which is saved in the text file.